# Cuando agrego/quito data en Vue no se actualiza en el browser

Tags: vue.js

Quizás esta pregunta es super novata pero me cuesta entender como resolverlo.

Estoy aprendiendo con Vue, estaba haciendo unos ejercicios simples (ni siquiera estoy usando componentes) y practicaba subiendo los archivos a un servidor compartido que tengo.

El asunto es que a medida que iba creciendo lo que estaba creando, fui agregando más valores a data y en mi HTML iba haciendo nuevas interpolaciones.

El problema es que me di cuenta, de que cuando lo veía desde algún otro browser que hubiera visto la página antes pareciera que no cargaba las variables data nuevas que había agregado. Me tocaba hacer un hard refresh (mayus + f5) o borrar los datos del navegador para que volviera a renderizar toda la página con el JS nuevamente, hay alguna forma de resolver esto al cliente sin pedirle que borre sus datos de navegación si agrego nuevas variables en data?

Gracias de antemano

En realidad es algo super simple, me di cuenta que dejo de renderizar después de que agregue un nuevo objeto en Data.

Mi js

```
let app = new Vue({

    el: "#app",
    data: {
        compartir: {
            producto1: {
                name: "Terrine De Cerdo",
                description: "80GR",
                price: "4.000"
            },
            producto2: {
                name: "Terrine de Foie Gras",
                description: "Mi - Cuit // 60GR",
                price: "6.000"
            },
            producto3: {
                name: "Plato de 3 Charcuteria",
                description: "Serrano - Chorizo - Salchichón  //  60gr",
                price: "5.000"
            },
            producto4: {
                name: "Plato 3 Quesos",
                description: "Laguiole - Roquefort - Brillat Savarin  //  60gr",
                price: "6.000"
            }
        },
        ensaladas: {
            producto1: {
                name: "Lechuga con Nueces",
                description: "",
                price: "4.000"
            },
            producto2: {
                name: "Ensalada 4 Quesos",
                description: "con Nueces",
                price: "7.000"
            },
            producto3: {
                name: "Ensalada de Quinoa",
                description: "con Kale, Tomate, Palta y Pepino",
                price: "7.000"
            }
        }
    })
```

y mi HTML

```
<h1 class="text-center mt-5">A La Carta</h1>

        <div class="row mt-5 d-flex">
            <div class="col bar"></div>
            <h3 class="col-auto text-center">Entrada</h3>
            <div class="col bar"></div>
        </div>

        <div v-for="product in compartir" class="row d-flex mt-3 item">
            <h5 class="col-8">{{product.name}}</h5>
            <h6 class="col-4 text-right">{{product.price}}</h6>
            <span class="col-12">{{product.description}}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="row mt-5 d-flex">
            <div class="col bar"></div>
            <h3 class="col-auto text-center">ENSALADAS</h3>
            <div class="col bar"></div>
        </div>

        <div v-for="product in ensaladas" class="row d-flex mt-3 item">
            <h5 class="col-8">{{product.name}}</h5>
            <h6 class="col-4 text-right">{{product.price}}</h6>
            <span class="col-12">{{product.description}}</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Agrega tu código

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! podes poner un ejemplo mas claro?

Comment: Listo, Agregado

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar agregando las metaetiquetas para el control de caché:

```html
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Debes tener en cuenta que aunque los navegadores la lean, los proxies no.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, hay algun lugar donde pueda ampliar esta informacion? igual voy a probar para intentar de entender como va eso

Comment: Si, la [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) tiene buena información.